# As3 different between set the to null and .dispose()

Tags: actionscript-3

I am come to optimize my flash application.

Just a quick question what's the different to null and dispose?

and what situation to use which?

Thanks very much for any suggestion.

Comment: someone have vote down to both question and answer. please at least leave the answer why is incorrect so help everyone who is confused with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting to null is safer, as it allows GC to collect an object only after it becomes unreferenced from anywhere. If you, for example, dispose() a BitmapData which is still referenced, you will receive an exception. If you are absolutely sure that a certain object is not referenced from anywhere, for example, if the BitmapData in question is temporary, and there is only one reference to it, you can use dispose() to free memory. The best solution in case of rapid allocation/deallocation of temporary objects will be reserving memory for them and actually reusing them when you need to.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `null` and `dispose()`:

`null` eliminates one reference to an object which occupies memory.

`dispose()` calls code which can do any variety of things, but is typically used to set one or more internal references to `null`.

I have habituated myself to add a public `dispose()` call to any object which creates, owns or manages another object which occupies memory and which may need to be garbage collected at some point in the future. In fact, I created an interface called `IDisposable` which ensures that I do not forget to add the necessary calls:

```
interface IDisposable
{
    function get isDisposed():Boolean;
    function dispose():void;
}
```

Later, in any object which implements the interface...

```
private var _isDisposed:Boolean = false;
public function get isDisposed():Boolean
{
    return _isDisposed;
}

public function dispose():void
{
    if( isDisposed )  return;
    //  TODO: Call dispose() on any owned objects
    //  and set all complex objects to null.
    _isDisposed = true;
}
```